# How can I depend on every matrix job?

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a GitHub Actions workflow using `matrix` to scale out multiple jobs. I need to create subsequence job which depends on each individual `matrix` job.

For example, I have below matrix:

```
jobs:
  example_matrix:
    strategy:
      matrix:
        version: [10, 12, 14]
    steps:
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.version }}
```

I'd like to have another 3 jobs depend on `[10, 12, 14]` separately. Like:

```
example_matrix-10   ->  sub10
example_matrix-12   ->  sub12
example_matrix-14   ->  sub14
```

If I define another matrix for the job `sub`, they will be run after all jobs in the first matrix finish. The only thing I can think of is to use `action` inside each `example_matrix` job. Is there a way to achieve it via `job`?

Comment: Why not just put the steps from subX in the job you're already running? You can't currently "need" a specific matrix job.

Comment: because the subX jobs are too many. I'd like to split them into multiple small jobs and some of them are resuable workflows